# Strange Biblatex behaviour when citing two different entries with the same first author

Tags: biblatex, author-number

I have two different references with different years but same first authors. I expect the outcome of citings to be Doe et al. (2005) and Doe et al. (2007). However the produce output is John, Mike, and Dave (2005) and John, Mike, Plank, et al. (2007)

What is going on here and how can I fix it?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[a4paper, top=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=4cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, date=year, firstinits=true, natbib=true]{biblatex}
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    \usepackage{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @article{doe1,
  title={Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet},
  author={John, D. and Mike, L. and Dave, O. },
  journal={Some Journal},
  volume={14},
  number={10},
  pages={2959-2967},
  year={2005},
}

@article{doe2,
  title={Placeholder placeholder placeholder},
  author={John, D. and Mike, L. and Plank, R. and Dave, O. },
  journal={Another Journal},
  volume={7},
  number={5},
  pages={757-762},
  year={2007},
}

\end{filecontents*}


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

\section{mwe}
{
 \citet{doe1}, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus a fermentum tortor. Curabitur lacinia feugiat eros. \citet{doe2}, aenean sagittis pulvinar orci id sodales. Aenean vulputate leo elit, vitae euismod odio cursus sed. Integer nec risus semper, lobortis arcu nec, sodales urna. Sed convallis vitae justo nec vehicula. Maecenas eleifend, erat sit amet ultricies ultricies, mi nibh hendrerit arcu, in consequat leo dui vitae eros.  
}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, I failed to spot that answer. This is a duplicate indeed.